# What are your most-recommended Visual Studio preferences?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

There are so many little options and settings within Microsoft Visual Studio. Which adjustments do you recommend to others?

Comment: Nice question. I'm browsing the answers with my VS options window open!

Answer (score 39):

**Line Numbers**

- Tools > Options
- Text Editor > All Languages > General
- Display: Line Numbers

[image: Visual Studio Line Numbers]

Comment: I'd prefer Cntrl + g to go to a specific line. :)

Comment: Line numbers are helpful when you're working, locally or remotely, with another developer.  "Look at lines 25-30."

Comment: WEll you can just look at the status bar and check the line you are instead of having 1/4 inch took for nothing about 95% of time ;)

Comment: Like Daok said - this seems like  HUGE waste of space and I don't think I can ever remember needing them.  CTRL-G also works for me.

Comment: Line numbers also indicate how much is hidden inside collapsed regions, something you can't see from a single number on the status bar.

Answer (score 16):

Environment->General->Animate environment tools  => OFF.

Speeds UI responsiveness by 82%.

Comment: yaah 74% of all percentages are made up on the spot !

Comment: Most lifeguards spend up to 40% of their lives in slow motion. Little known fact.

Comment: Dont' see this option in VS2019

Answer (score 14):

I've never found dynamic help to be either dynamic or helpful, and just tends to slow visual studio down, so using regedit:

```
registry key:
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Visual Studio\x.x\Dynamic Help
value:
    Never Show DH on F1 = yes
```

I'm also keen on setting the following in Options->Projects and Solutions:

- Show Output window when build starts - checked
  (IMHO easiest way to spot build errors)
- Track Active Item in Solution Explorer - unchecked
  (stops every project ending up fully expanded in Solution Explorer)
  [image: Visual Studio Preferences]

Comment: This screenshot makes me think I need to clean my display.

Answer (score 8):

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

Setup a shortcut to close the active document. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> in my case.

Comment: control-f4 is a lot harder to hit than something like ctrl-w (which most apps use to close windows, both in Windows and OSX).

Comment: I use Control-W, which is the same as the shortcut to close the current tab in some browsers.

Comment: Wow that search window is micro-sized.  4 lines for showing commands available?

Answer (score 8):

Gotta have the tab indention set up right.

Also, Consolas & Color Themed - white backgrounds hurt my eyes

Comment: And what, pray, is 'right' tab indentation? (runs for cover...)

Comment: Purely subjective of course, but I prefer double spaces instead of tabs, so I like to set VS to convert it as such.

Answer (score 8):

**Option Strict On**

Tools > Options

Projects and Solutions > VB Defaults

Default project settings: Option Strict: On

[image: Option Strict]

Answer (score 6):

Personally i hate that VS defaults to "Tab to Spaces" when you are developing in C#. This is so awkward to work with and unnecessary.

Yes, i know there are issues with Tabs but honestly, did any of you ever encounter them coding in C# on Windows?

Comment: You will if you have a team where one developer doesn't like the default tab width.

Comment: That is just a display issue and can be configured on each computer without affecting anyone else. However, if one developer does have "tabs to spaces" on and all source files he touched are converted to spaces ... well, that just sucks.

Comment: I totally agree - to save others time: Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Tabs > Keep tabs

Comment: getting your team to use anything but the default settings is an uphill battle.

Comment: and you can use intelligent diffing software if you do run into whitespace commits.

Comment: I hate to start a religious war, but only infidels would check in files with \t instead of spaces.

Comment: I don't get it, why are tabs evil?  I've never had any issues.

Comment: "Insert spaces" is evil, If by any reason code gets indented when typing a '}' then all tabs upwards are converted to spaces. That is really a pain in the @ss when diffing the change log, or even worse when doing a Blame (thats the name of the operation in TortoiseSVN, don't know how it's commonly knonwn in other tools) of the source file.

Comment: When I see code with TAB indentation, there are always some lines with SPACE indentation too: sometimes one presses spacebar automatically to indent a 1 or more spaces, visually aligning the cursor with other code. Mixed tabs & spaces only work with one specific tab size, and backspace will behave inconsistent. Expand to spaces if you want to be sure your code is consistently indented.
@steffenj, @Fede The "my DVCS will complain once" argument can be used against implementing any coding standard.

Answer (score 5):

Several have mentioned custom keybindings.  Here are handy default keybinding reference posters…

**[Microsoft Visual Basic Default Keybindings reference poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=255b8cf1-f6bd-4b55-bb42-dd1a69315833&displaylang=en)**

> A high quality, print-ready PDF
>   containing the useful keybindings for
>   developers that choose the Visual
>   Basic developer profile in Visual
>   Studio 2008 or use Visual Basic
>   Express.

**[Microsoft Visual C# Default Keybindings reference poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E5F902A8-5BB5-4CC6-907E-472809749973&displaylang=en)**

> Visual C# in Visual Studio 2008 and
>   Visual C# 2008 Express Edition Wall
>   chart showing useful keyboard
>   shortcuts for Visual C# programming
>   language.

I like Microsoft's **instructions**:

> 1. Download and extract PDF
> 2. Send to favorite full color printer/copier
> 3. Hang on wall
> 4. Code
> 5. Smile

Answer (score 4):

Set the active document you're working on to display in the solution explorer.  I've seen a lot of people hunting for their current doc if the project gets too big.

Tools -> Options.
**Make sure show all settings is checked.**

Click on Projects and Solutions.
Enable the Track Active Item in Explorer checkbox.

[alt text http://img370.imageshack.us/img370/4821/trackactivedocumentqv2.gif](http://img370.imageshack.us/img370/4821/trackactivedocumentqv2.gif)

Comment: I personally find this distracting.  A keyboard shortcut that found the active item would be nice though.

Comment: I found it distracting too. So I use Add-in (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/VSHelper.aspx) to quickly find document when I need it.

Answer (score 4):

Environment => General => Recent files

24 items shown in Window menu

24 items shown in recently used lists

Environment => General

Show status bar ON

Animate environment tools OFF

Answer (score 4):

Prevent Visual Studio from renaming pasted controls

[How do I prevent Visual Studio from renaming my controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484327/how-do-i-prevent-visual-studio-from-renaming-my-controls#484344)

Answer (score 4):

I'm somewhat surprised to be the first person recommending [Visual Studio Hacks](http://visualstudiohacks.com/) for a lot of suggestions of this variety

Answer (score 4):

Visible white space. (Edit -> Advanced -> View White Space)

[image: Free Image Hosting by FreeImageHosting.net]

The default color is too strong.  I immediately change it to silver. (Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Visible White Space).

[image: Silver visible white space]

On some displays, even silver is too strong, and I create a "light silver".

[image: Free Image Hosting by FreeImageHosting.net]

Comment: This would be easier to follow if your screenshots weren't overly compressed. Next time you might want to use png rather than jpeg, it is lossless and for screenshots without embedded photos usually ends up smaller than a resasonable quality jpeg.

Make whitespace visible using: Edit>Advanced>View White Space
or pressing Ctrl+E,Ctrl+S

To set the colour, use Tools>Option>Fonts and Colors>Visible White Space.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. FreeImageHosting.net isn't doing a great job for me, either. I've edited to state the menu items in the text.

Answer (score 4):

**Window Layouts**

This really isn't a setting but something I always do is back up my settings via **Tools > Import and Export Settings**.

I make sure to back up my window layouts for both single and multiple monitors.  It saves frustration when moving from my multi-monitor setup to a single monitor for a presentation.

Not to mention, it makes it easy to get up and running on a new PC.

Answer (score 3):

**Fixedsys Font**

Tools > Options

Environment > Fonts and Colors

Font: Fixedsys

[image: Visual Studio font]

Comment: Consolas is much better imho.

Comment: Droid Sans Mono 10pt has reduced my eye fatigue measurably.

Answer (score 3):

**Always show solution**

Tools > Options

Projects and Solutions

Always show solution

[image: Always show solution]

Answer (score 2):

**Source View**

Tools > Options

HTML Designer > General

Start pages in: Source View

[image: Visual Studio Start pages in Source View]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be available in the Express version and that makes me sad.

Comment: Bouvard, remmember to check the "Show All Settings" button, at the buttom of the dialog

Answer (score 2):

Check out this thread for the Color theme options for Visual Studio 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141371/which-visual-studio-color-theme

And consolas is my favourite font

Answer (score 2):

This applies to winform projects.

Instead of opening the form in design mode by default, you can configure VS to open the code editor instead. This is configured by right-clicking on a form in the solution explorer and choosing the "Open with" option.  This gives you a dialog that allows you to specify the default option when double-clicking on a file.

Answer (score 2):

In a control's properties, setting **GenerateMembers to false** for items you don't need (labels, etc). It's not a specifically Visual-Studio thing, more related to the platform, but mixed with the contextual list of objects and functions, it just clears up so much clutter.

Answer (score 2):

When designing a form:

View > Tab Order

Allows you you specify and control your TabIndexes easily (much more so than setting them by hand!)

Answer (score 1):

Its all about [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) ;) Gives you tons of shortcuts which are so useful I can no longer work without them. I don't get on with the intellisense though, so I've turned that off.

[This](http://blog.jpboodhoo.com/BDDAutoHotKeyScriptUpdateTake2.aspx) is incredibly useful, allows you to write underscores with the space bar when writing long test method names.

Answer (score 1):

**Un-Bold Brace Matching**

Tools > Options

Environment > Fonts and Colors

Display items: Brace Matching (Hilight)

uncheck Bold

Answer (score 1):

Find and Replace window’s "Search Hidden Text" checkbox.

It's not really a preference but it is indispensable. It sure is frustrating when you don’t notice that it "magically" unchecked itself.

Answer (score 0):

Besides, Line Numbers, the first thing I always do in a newly-installed IDE is set the **`Edit.GoToDefinition`** keyboard shortcut.

Tools > Options > Keyboard

Comment: But isn't what I'm used to.  To each his/her own.  :)