# How do I prevent Visual Studio from renaming my controls?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

If I paste something like

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListExpirationDate" runat="server" />
```

onto an ASPX file that already has a control with ID `DropDownListExpirationDate`, it will rename the newly-pasted control as `DropDownList1`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" />
```

I'd rather it didn't.  I'd rather it just paste exactly what I copied.

Is there a way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

After a quick check(!)....

Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Miscellaneous

Uncheck 'Auto ID elements on paste in Source view'.

Comment: [Apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695992/disable-auto-id-elements-in-visual-studio-2013) this no longer works in VS2013.

Comment: I don't have v2013 so I can't comment, but I would assume there will be a comparable setting. Perhaps a 2013 owner can advise?

Comment: No longer there.  Weird thing is, when I search via Quick Launch for 'auto id', I see an entry for 'Text Editor -> Html (Web Forms) -> Miscellaneous - Auto id elements on ...', but clicking it takes me to that tab in options but there is no such option to turn on and off.