# Stop Visual Studio from appending numbers to the end of new controls

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am wondering if there is any way to stop Visual Studio 2010 from appending a number to the end of the ID on new controls I create.  For example, when I add a new TextBox, I would prefer that it do this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server">
```

Instead of this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server">
```

It would make it easier to rename them appropriately, so I don't have to arrow/mouse over and delete the number each time.  As I was writing this, the "Questions that may already have your answer" suggested this:

[How do I prevent Visual Studio from renaming my controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484327/how-do-i-prevent-visual-studio-from-renaming-my-controls)

which admittedly was the biggest part of my annoyance, but that appears to turn off putting in an `ID=""` field altogether, not just for pasted controls.  It would still be helpful to turn off the numbering for new, non-pasted controls and have it not rename pasted ones as well.  At the moment I'm working with ASP.NET, but it would be nice if it there was a way to do it for WinForms as well.

Before anyone suggests it, I do know that allowing it to append the numbers prevents name conflicts should I not rename them appropriately.  However, I would much rather have it fail to compile so I know to fix the issue now (if I forget to name something properly) rather than find random `"TextBox1"` items lying around in the code later on.

Answer (score 0):

in visual studio goto:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Miscellaneous

Uncheck 'Auto ID elements on paste in Source view'.

Comment: The link included in my original question already has that answer.  Unfortunately, it turns off including the ID tag altogether, not just the numbering.