# Disable Visual Studio automatic id renaming

Tags: visual-studio-2010, event-handling

How do you disable the annoying automatic renaming of id in Visual Studio when you copy paste? For example, if you have

```
<p id="myID"></p>
```

and you copy and paste it in the same file, Visual Studio renames it to

```
<p id="P1"></p>
```

I want it to highlight the duplicate id but not change it automatically.

Thanks

Comment: [See here](http://www.reddybrek.com/post/How-to-stop-Visual-Studio-renaming-ID-values-when-pasting-content.aspx)

Comment: Wow, how did you find that post, i searched the same thing on google and didnt find anything that worked. Thanks!

Comment: Ironically, I copy/pasted your question title into Google, just to see what would turn up lol.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent Visual Studio from renaming my controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484327/how-do-i-prevent-visual-studio-from-renaming-my-controls)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> See here – ajp15243
>
> Step1: Go to the menu bar and click on 'Tools' and then 'Options'.
>
> Step 2: On the popup screen than appears there is a little checkbox in
>   the lower left corner that says 'Show All Settings'. Make sure that is
>   selected.
>
> Step 3: Expand the 'TextEditor' option and expand the 'HTML' option.
>
> Step 4: Click on 'Miscellaneous' and untick the option 'Auto ID
>   elements on paste in Source view'.
>
> Step 5: Click OK and now when you paste any html content or code with
>   the same ID values as what is in your project Visual Studio will not
>   rename the IDs.

Comment: I suppose I could have just posted this as an answer myself, but I'll just use this to say that you can (and should!) accept your answer to your own question if it sufficiently answers the question.

Comment: This no longer works for visual studio 2013... They have either remove the option or moved/renamed it to the point I cannot find it.

Comment: See workaround for VS 2013 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695992/disable-auto-id-elements-in-visual-studio-2013