# Disable "Auto ID elements" in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2013

In Tools > Options, I cannot find the setting to disable auto-renaming of elements which are pasted in HTML source view.

[It used to be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/484344/895218): Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Miscellaneous > Auto ID elements on paste in Source view.  But that option is gone in Visual Studio 2013.

How can I disable the auto-renaming?

Comment: Looks like someone has created the same issue on the Microsoft Connect site a few days ago.  It is under review. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806446/asp-net-web-forms-development-unable-to-disable-auto-id-generation-on-paste-using-new-version-of-visual-studio-2013

Comment: To save other people time, unfortunately trying to add the registry key back of 'AutoIdSnippets' 0 doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Same issue here. Hope someone finds a resolution to this. Very annoying.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For now the best solution seems to be a workaround that was posted by a user on the [Microsoft Connect website](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806446/asp-net-web-forms-development-unable-to-disable-auto-id-generation-on-paste-using-new-version-of-visual-studio-2013) which is to paste the code as a comment.

> Fool the IDE that we're not pasting code (thus he won't alter it). How ? Paste a comment ! How to do that in real life ? Here is how I do it (feel free to suggest other ways!):
>
> 1) Place cursor where I want to paste code 
>   2) ctrl-k, ctrl-c (i.e.
>   comment region. Since no region was selected, an empty comment is
>   inserted and our cursor Inside of it) 3) ctrl-v (paste content that is
>   believed to be a comment by the IDE) 4) ctrl-k, ctrl-u (i.e.
>   un-commenting the current comment we're in!

Comment: This workaround is hideous!  How can this actually be a thing!?

Comment: @Paul: Could not agree with you more!

Comment: To automate the workaround see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747485/is-there-any-plugin-to-disable-auto-id-on-paste-on-visual-studio-2013

Comment: Such a great(!) solution by MS Connect. Pretty weird that this option does not exist in VS2017 whilst it is there in 2019 and versions earlier than 2013.

Comment: @ErdemKAYA You mentioned that this is there in VS2019, but I don't see it. Can you please specify where you find it in VS2019?

Comment: Fast forward to 2022, and this is truly the only way... -10 points to Microsoft for removing a great feature.

Answer (score 0):

The auto ID assigning is made only if the ID is used by another control on the same page.

Copy the code and paste in external editor like Notepad++, then copy it again from NP++ and paste it in the code editor page, the ID should remain the same.