# Is there any Plugin to disable "Auto ID on Paste" on Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-2013

I saw [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695992/disable-auto-id-elements-in-visual-studio-2013) about the "Auto ID on Paste" tool being unavailable on newer versions of Visual Studio, and I know about the workaround that is being currently used (comment a line, paste, undo comment)

But I'm not comfortable with those workarounds, I think it would be easier if I could just install one plugin that allows me to paste elements without generating IDs automatically.

Is there any plugin that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To automate the workaround, you can create the following command in [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) and assign a keyboard shortcut to it:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.CommentSelection")
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Paste")
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.UncommentSelection")
```

Comment: This is not a desirable solution because sometimes you want to copy/paste only a word or two inside a code line, and the solution would comment the whole line and erase everything it was inside only to paste the content. But this plugin is amazing, so I'm marking as solved.

Comment: A probably better workaround command (VB) considering this scenario as well: DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetText()

Comment: somehow this command makes a huge delay on paste, and also messes up the indentation