# How to disable Auto ID in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When copying and pasting HTML, VS helpfully renames all my variables to things like "Div1" & "Img1". Why!

I remember when using VS 2010 I think it was, there was a setting that allowed us to turn this "feature" off. Seems that feature no longer exists.

Are there any plugins or extensions or workarounds for this problem?

Seems that people have been complaining about this for years now:

[How do I prevent Visual Studio from renaming my controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484327/how-do-i-prevent-visual-studio-from-renaming-my-controls)

[Disable "Auto ID elements" in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695992/disable-auto-id-elements-in-visual-studio-2013)

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806446/asp-net-web-forms-development-unable-to-disable-auto-id-generation-on-paste-using-new-version-of-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest workaround.
Simply make a comment first, then paste into the comment. When uncommenting, it will not apply Auto ID.

As a keyboard shortcut, it's CTRL+K,C,V,K,U on a new line.
Comment (KC), Paste (V), Uncomment (KU).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command (Language: C#) for my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to paste text as is without renaming variables:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
{
    EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
    ts.Insert(System.Windows.Clipboard.GetText());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can disable this auto-tag closing in Options > Text Editor > HTML u can find here everything about html editor.Search for AutoTag or Format Html on paste!

Comment: No such setting in VS 2017 anymore