# What might be intercepting and tampering with my clipboard in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017, if I copy

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="userControl1" runat="server">
```

and then try to paste it, it comes out as

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="Placeholder[n]" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

where `[n]` is some whole number; however, when I paste it into any other application, it comes out correct.

How should I approach solving this problem? Is it possible an extension is the culprit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because a control with that ID already exists within that `webform`.

Visual Studio will try to make sure that duplicate ID's aren't inserted into your `.aspx`. When you remove the pre-existing control, it will '*paste correctly*'.

You can turn this functionality off in the options menu:

Tools>Options>Text Editor>HTML>Miscellaneous>Auto ID On Paste/Format HTML/Close Brace

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695992/disable-auto-id-elements-in-visual-studio-2013) might help you.