# How do I prevent Sharp Develop from renaming my controls?

Tags: visual-studio, sharpdevelop

I'm using a TabControl. I want to paste lots of controls from one tab to another but I want to only add a number at the end of the current name of each control so I don't have to name them all over again.

Is there a way to prevent auto renaming in Sharp Develop?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484327/how-do-i-prevent-visual-studio-from-renaming-my-controls) method is of no use in SharpDevelop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am assuming you are using the Windows Forms designer in SharpDevelop.

Currently SharpDevelop has the same behaviour as Visual Studio. If you copy and paste a control, say a button, it will create a new button with a name of button1. The Windows Forms designer needs a unique name for each control so they have to be given a new name.

One possibility would be to only add a number at the end of the control and keep the rest of the name. However this is not currently implemented. To get this feature you would have to modify SharpDevelop's source code. However I am not sure this is straightforward to do.