# How do I get rid of the dots!

Tags: visual-studio

I was coding on a project in VS2008 and I tried to hit CTR + R +E to encapsulate a field as a property(feature of resharper) and I fummble fingered, now I have dots everywhere I have spaces and I cant figure out how to get rid of it.
e.g.

```
using.System;

Namespace.EgNamespace
{
....public.class.TestClass
....{
........public.void.TestMethod()
........{
............return;
........}

....}
}
```

The dots are centered but its very close to that. I have been serching the tools->options->Text Editor for a toggle to turn it off but I am at a lost.

Comment: This has to be one of my favorite questions..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Ctrl+R, Ctrl+W` or

`Edit –> Advanced –> View White Space`

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like visible white space a lot, but only if it's changed from the strong green to a mild gray.  See [What are your most-recommended Visual Studio preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189118/what-are-your-most-recommended-visual-studio-preferences/484590#484590)