# How to avoid dots in VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Accidentally I pressed some keys while writing C# code in VS2008 and space characters replaced by . and enter key replaced by some square boxes, now how do I reset the editor
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably viewing whitespace, duplicate topic here:

[How do I get rid of the dots!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784039/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-dots)

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+R, Ctrl+W to toggle this setting (without releasing the Ctrl Key).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have "View White Space" turned on. To change this go to Edit -> Advanced -> View White Space.

Answer (score 0):

Check the menu Edit->Advanced->View white space

Answer (score -2):

Tools->Import and Export Settings -> Reset all Settings

Comment: Not very helpful as there are almost certainly other settings you don't want to restore to factory default.

Comment: Read the question. "How do i RESET the editor" ? Reset = factory default. However you taking the time to leave a negative comment was very helpful! Good Job!